# Cython C-array initialization

Tags: cython

I would like to do

```
cdef int mom2calc[3]
mom2calc[0] = 1
mom2calc[1] = 2
mom2calc[2] = 3
```

in a more compact way. Something similar to

```
cdef int mom2calc[3] = [1, 2, 3]
```

which is an invalid Cython syntax.

Note:

```
cdef int* mom2calc = [1, 2, 3]
```

is not an option because I cannot (automatically) converted it to a memory view.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```python
cdef int mom2calc[3]
mom2calc[:] = [1, 2, 3]
```

This works on raw pointers (although it isn't bounds checked then), memory views and fixed-sized arrays. It only works in one dimension, but that's often enough:

```python
cdef int mom2calc[3][3]
mom2calc[0][:] = [1, 2, 3]
mom2calc[1][:] = [4, 5, 6]
mom2calc[2][:] = [7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: You can do it in one line as such: `cdef int[3][3] arr2d = [range(3), (3, 4, 5), [6, 7, 8]]`. Note this works nicely with various iterable types too.

Answer (score 9):

```
cdef int[3] mom2calc = [1, 2, 3]
```

This is how it should be done. Example of C-array initialization in Cython tests is e.g. [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/0.29.13-514-gac1c9fe47/tests/run/carray_coercion.pyx#L147).

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is not currently easy to do with the `nogil` option, see this github bug: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3160

Answer (score 0):

For multidimensional arrays the syntax is:

```py
cdef int[3][3] arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Notice where the array size `[3][3]` is placed right after the type.